# SQLで集計（この部分のSQLあり）した上でDBに日付のデータも保存するにはどのようにするのがいいでしょうか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql, sql

RubyonRailsで記事の投稿を集計（時間別）する処理の実装をしております。

現在、次のようなSQLを実行し、集計した結果をDBに保存し、Web上の画面に表示させるということをやりたいです。

SQL

> SELECT date_format(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d-%H') as hour, count(id) 
>   FROM `articles` WHERE (created_at >= "2016-05-29" AND created_at < "2016-05-30") 
>   GROUP BY hour;

集計用テーブル

> Report
>   　　id(integer)
>   　　hour(datetipe)
>   　　count(integer)

SQLを実行してから、DBに保存するところの処理はまだ考えている途中のため、実装できてませんが、
現在、問題視している点は、hour(datetipe)の部分です。

というのも、集計するときにdate_format(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d-%H')という風にしているため、
そのまま、DBに保存ができなくなってしまいます。

%Y-%m-%d-%Hという風に整形している理由は後でも述べますが、2016年05月29日（水）というふうに表示させるため、区切りを認識する文字をいれておきたかったためです。

それに対して私が考えた方法は次の2つです。

```
1) hourをstring型に変更する
２） SQL実行の際にdate_format(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d-%H')を使わず、上手く時間別に集計する
```

1)については、string型で保存をし、画面を表示する際に、Controllerで
stringからdatetime型に変換する処理を入れるといいかなと思っております。
（変換する理由は曜日を取得したいためです）

また、画面側では
2016年05月29日（水）
と言った風に表示できるようにしたいと思っております。

1)のやり方だと頑張ればできそうな気がするのですが、そもそもstring型で日付を保存することに違和感を感じてしまいます。

しかし、2)については方法がわからず困っております。

以上をふまえまして、アドバイスを頂けますと幸いです。

よろしくお願いします。

### 追記

表題の問題はmetropolis様のご回答により解決しました。

今回は時間別に集計するため、集計キーをDATE_FORMAT で %Y-%m-%d %H:00:00 に変換して DATETIME 型にキャストするという方法ができました。

しかし、今後、もし月別に集計したいとなったとき、集計キーは(2016-04)みたいな形になります。
こういった場合はDATETIME型もしくはDATE型にキャストできないのかなと思いました。

こういう場合は、String型で保存するしかないでしょうか？

Comment: 質問にクローズ票を投じます。オフトピックである理由: 本件の問題が解決したのちに、追記として別件の質問が追加されています。これらは、別々の質問として取り扱われるべきだと考えます。

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQLであれば、date_trunc
https://www.postgresql.jp/document/9.5/html/functions-datetime.html#functions-datetime-trunc
を実行した列で集約すれば、望みの値が得られるように思います

SQLのサンプルも置いておきます
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/9925

```
WITH articles AS (
SELECT
  id, created_at
FROM (
  VALUES
    (1, TIMESTAMP '2016-07-15 00:00:00'),
    (2, TIMESTAMP '2016-07-15 00:01:00'),
    (3, TIMESTAMP '2016-07-15 01:00:00'),
    (4, TIMESTAMP '2016-07-15 01:01:00'),
    (5, TIMESTAMP '2016-07-15 01:02:00'),
    (6, TIMESTAMP '2016-07-15 02:00:00')
) AS T(id, created_at)
)
SELECT
  hour_trunc,
  count(*) AS hour_count
FROM (  
  SELECT
    id,
    date_trunc('hour', created_at) AS hour_trunc,
    count(created_at) over (partition by date_trunc('hour', created_at))
  FROM
    articles
) T
GROUP BY
  hour_trunc
ORDER BY
  hour_trunc
;
```

集約絡みでうまくいかないことがあれば、window functionを使うと多くの問題が解決できると思います
機会があれば挑戦してみてください
(でも、RailsのSQLbuilderは生成してくれないと思います...)

---

mysqlでは TIME_FORMAT するか TO_SECONDS の剰余を取るほかないようです...
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/69182

```
SELECT
  sec,
  FROM_UNIXTIME(sec * 3600 - TO_SECONDS('1970-01-01 00:00:00')) as my_date_time,
  count(sec) AS count
FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    updated_at,
    CAST(TO_SECONDS(updated_at) / 3600 AS SIGNED INTEGER) AS sec,
    TIME_FORMAT(updated_at, '%Y%m%d%h') AS ymdh
  FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS id, TIMESTAMP '2016-07-15 00:00:00' AS updated_at FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, TIMESTAMP '2016-07-15 00:01:00' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, TIMESTAMP '2016-07-15 01:00:00' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT 4, TIMESTAMP '2016-07-15 01:01:00' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT 5, TIMESTAMP '2016-07-15 01:02:00' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT 6, TIMESTAMP '2016-07-15 02:00:00' FROM DUAL
  ) AS T
) AS T
GROUP BY
  sec
ORDER BY
  sec
;
```